# Is there something like RouteConfig.cs in .Net Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I'm trying to follow Adam Freeman's book "ASP .NET MVC". In this book there is chapter where author suggests putting routes to special configuration file `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`. It looks like nice, but I'm trying to implement it with the help of .Net Core. I had not found special place for routes and I put routes into `Startup.cs`. But it looks like pretty ugly. Maybe somebody knows elegant solution for this case?

Here is code of my `Startup.cs`

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // services are here ..
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            // /
            routes.MapRoute(null, "", new
            {
                controller = "Products",
                action = "List",
                category = "", page = 1
            });

            // Page2
            routes.MapRoute(null,
                "Page{page}",
                new
                {
                    controller = "Products",
                    action = "List",
                    category = ""
                },
                new { page = @"\d+" }
            );

            // Category
            routes.MapRoute(null,
                "{category}",
                new
                {
                    controller = "Products",
                    action = "List",
                    page = 1
                });

            // Category/Page2
            routes.MapRoute(null,
                "{category}/Page{page}",
                new
                {
                    controller = "Products",
                    action = "List",
                },
                new
                {
                    page = @"\d+"
                });
        });
    }
}
```

P.S .Net Core version is 2.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put them in another file:

```
public static class Routing
{
    public static void Include(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            // /
            routes.MapRoute(null, "", new
            {
                controller = "Products",
                action = "List",
                category = "",
                page = 1
            });

            // Page2
            routes.MapRoute(null,
                "Page{page}",
                new
                {
                    controller = "Products",
                    action = "List",
                    category = ""
                },
                new { page = @"\d+" }
            );
        }
        );
    }
}
```

And then call it in the `Startup' class:

```
public class Startup
{
    ...
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        Routing.Include(app);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Could also convert it to an extension method since the class is static.

Comment: Sure, Just convert method to this: `public static void IncludeRoutes(this IApplicationBuilder app)` And for call `app.IncludeRoutes();`

Comment: But it hides inside that I use `app.UseMvc()` and this file can become very big too. Is  the only this way?

Comment: It's not for decreasing the size of the file, it helps to make `Startup` file seems better and easy to manage.

Comment: I'd rather write an extension method accordingly: `public static void UseMvcWithRoutes(this IApplicationBuilder app)` and call `app.UseMvcWithRoutes()`